# Child folder directory targeting different repo

Tags: git, github

What I want to do:

```
Main folder -> Github
  Child folder -> Website git (e.g. openshift)
```

I would like the whole project to be available on Github (child folder as well). However I have included a child folder which is a website repo so it's like a second git inside the main git.

Is it possible to handle this kind of structure with git? If so how should my git configuration be (remote + branches) and how can I set for the child folder the default directory?

Comment: Do you want to include the other repository's files or do you want to include the other repository as submodule?

Comment: @knittl can you define the "other repository"? -> main or child. I do not have any external repos. Both are created by myself. I want `/` folder **with all its subfolders** to aim one repo and the `/child/` folder to aim another. Does it make more sense?

Comment: So you want to have a submodule? Two distinct repositories, where the main repository references a specific commit of the child repository?